# Is every finitely generated group the fundamental group of some finite topological space?

Tags: general-topology, fundamental-groups

Can every finitely generated group be realized as the fundamental group of some **finite** topological space?

The motivation for my question is that the topological space on the finite point set $X=\{v_1,v_2,e_1,e_2\}$, with the topology generated by $\{e_1,e_2,\{v_1,e_1,e_2\},\{v_2,e_1,e_2\}\}$, has a fundamental group of $\mathbb Z$. The idea is that $X$ resembles a circle in a loose sense; $v_1$ and $v_2$ are like vertices, and $e_1$ and $e_2$ are disjoint paths connecting $v_1$ to $v_2$. (I think this is called the digital circle? Its universal covering space is the [digital line](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2671212/show-that-the-digital-line-topology-on-the-integers-is-connected/2671325)).

Using this same idea, you can make a finite topological space which resembles any finite graph $G=(V,E)$. The points are $V\cup E$, and the topology is the finest topology for which every $e\in E$ is open and every $v\in V$ is closed. This is equivalent to saying that sets of the form $\{e\}$ for $e\in E$ and $v\cup E_v$ for $v\in V$ are open, where $E_v$ are the edges which have $v$ as an endpoint. This means every finitely generated free group is the fundamental group of a finite topological space.

In the preceding paragraph, we made a finite topological space corresponding to any $1$ dimensional CW complex. I know that there is a $2$ dimensional cell complex whose fundamental group is any desired group (there is one vertex, the $1$-cells are generators, the $2$-cells are relations). It therefore seems like the goal is to extend this construction to make arbitrary finite $2$-complexes. I could not figure out how to do this.

Comment: Your topological space $X$ is called the [pseudocircle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudocircle).

Comment: Have you tried to study a simple case like $\mathbb{Z}_2$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, I figured it out. For every finite simplicial complex, there is a finite topological space with the same fundamental group. A simplicial complex defines a partial order on the simplices based on inclusion; the points of the topological space are the simplices, and the open sets are the upper sets of this partial order (so for each simplex $s$ there is an open set consisting of all simplices containing $s$ as a sub-simplex). Then you can mimic the CW complex construction using a simplicial complex to construct a simplicial complex with any given fundamental group.

Comment: This construction works for any simplicial complex to give a space (finite if the simplicial complex was finite) which is weak equivalent to it.  See my answer at https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3117871/86856 for some discussion.