# Find finite path connected topological space with $π_1 (X, x_0 ) \cong \Bbb Z/2\Bbb Z$

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, fundamental-groups

Find a finite non-empty topological space $X$ that satisfies:

- $X$ is path connected
- Its fundamental group $π_1 (X, x_0 ) \cong \Bbb Z/2\Bbb Z$ for $x_0 \in X$

Is the connected pair $\{\{0\},\{1\},\{0,1\}\}$ a good example of such space satisfying the first condition?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: The example you give is discrete, so certainly not path-connected. In any case, path-connected spaces with less than 3 points are simply-connected

Comment: For finite spaces, path connectedness is equivalent to connectedness.

Comment: @TsemoAristide yes I know for instance the example $\Bbb P_n(\Bbb R) = \Bbb S^n/ (\Bbb Z/2\Bbb Z)$ which has a fundamental group $\cong  \Bbb Z/2\Bbb Z$ but $\Bbb P_n(\Bbb R)$ it is not finite.

Comment: It looks like an example should be constructible from McCord's "Singular homology groups and homotopy groups of finite topological spaces". The punchline is that the homotopy type of any finite simplicial complex can be represented by a finite topology. I'm not too familiar with the paper yet, but it looks like it might be explicit enough to cook something up.

Comment: Thank you @William I will definitely take a look as I don't know much about simplicial complexes.

Comment: I think in principal I can apply the construction from McCord to a minimal triangulation of $\mathbb{RP}^2$ I found here: http://physbam.stanford.edu/~aanjneya/mridul_files/papers/real_projective.pdf . However the resulting space would be on a set of 27 points and I'm not sure it would be clear why it has $\pi_1\cong \mathbb{Z}/2$, except because "the theory says so". I'll see if I can cook up something smaller.

Comment: I don't know what you mean by your "connected pair".  If you mean the three-point space given by those three sets with the topology induced by the inclusion ordering as in my answer, then it is indeed a path-connected space (but I'm not sure why you're calling it a "pair").

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is a general theory of finite topological spaces which makes questions like this easy to answer.  In particular, here are some of the central theorems.

**Theorem 1**: Let $X$ be a preordered set.  Then $X$ can be given a topology by saying a subset $U\subseteq X$ is open iff for all $x\in U$ and $y\leq x$, $y\in U$.  Conversely, every finite topological space arises from a preordered set in this way and this gives an isomorphism of categories between the category of finite preordered sets and finite topological spaces (i.e., continuous maps are the same thing as order-preserving maps).

*Proof sketch*: The first part is easy, as is the statement that continuous maps are the same as order-preserving maps.  To prove every finite topological space arises in this way, given a topological space $X$, define a preorder $\leq$ by $x\leq y$ iff $y\in\overline{\{x\}}$.  Now verify that if $X$ is finite, its topology must coincide with the topology given by this preorder.

Using this theorem, we will treat finite preordered sets and finite topological spaces as interchangeable, and will always consider preordered sets as having the topology described above.

**Theorem 2**: Let $X$ and $Y$ be preordered sets and $f,g:X\to Y$ be order-preserving maps.  Then if $f(x)\leq g(x)$ for all $x$, $f$ and $g$ are homotopic as continuous maps.

*Proof*: Consider the homotopy $H(x,t)=f(x)$ for $t\in[0,1)$ and $H(x,1)=g(x)$.

**Theorem 3** (McCord): Let $X$ be a preordered set, and let $N(X)$ be its [nerve](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nerve_(category_theory)).  Then there is a natural map $|N(X)|\to X$ which is a weak homotopy equivalence.

This theorem is much deeper and harder to prove than the others.  You can find a proof in McCord's paper [*Singular homology groups and homotopy groups of finite topological spaces*](http://dx.doi.org/10.1215/S0012-7094-66-03352-7).

**Corollary**: Let $K$ be a simplicial complex and let $X$ be the partially ordered set of faces of $K$.  Then there is a weak homotopy equivalence $|K|\to X$.

To deduce the Corollary from Theorem 3, note that $N(X)$ is exactly the simplicial set corresponding to the first barycentric subdivision of $K$, and so there is a canonical homeomorphism $|K|\cong |N(X)|$.

Using the Corollary, we can now quickly get an answer to your question: just take any connected finite simplicial complex $K$ such that $\pi_1(|K|)\cong\mathbb{Z}/2$, and let $X$ be the poset of faces of $K$, considered as a topological space as in Theorem 1.  For instance, you could take $K$ to be a triangulation of $\mathbb{R}P^2$.

---

Alternatively, here is a modification of the idea in William's answer that works to give a smaller example than you can get from a triangulation of $\mathbb{R}P^2$ and without using the full power of Theorem 3.  We start with the poset $FS(4)$ which has four points $a,b,c,d$ ordered by $a,b\leq c,d$.  This poset is weak equivalent to $S^1$, and in particular $\pi_1(FS(4))\cong\mathbb{Z}$. (You can verify that $\pi_1(FS(4))\cong\mathbb{Z}$ without using Theorem 3 by explicitly constructing a universal cover.)  There is a double cover $p:FS(8)\to FS(4)$ corresponding to the subgroup of index $2$ in $\pi_1(FS(4))$.  Explicitly, we can write $FS(8)=\{a_1,a_2,b_1,b_2,c_1,c_2,d_1,d_2\}$ with the order $$a_1\leq c_1\geq b_1\leq d_1\geq a_2 \leq c_2 \geq b_2\leq d_2\geq a_1$$ and the $p$ is the obvious map that drops the subscripts.

Now the idea is to construct a finite "mapping cone" of $p$.  To do this, consider the poset $I(3)$ with three points $\{0,1/2,1\}$ ordered by $1/2\leq 0,1$.  (If this ordering seems strange, note that the nerve of this poset has two non-degenerate 1-simplices $\{0,1/2\}$ and $\{1/2,1\}$ which are glued together at $1/2$, so this is a finite model for an interval with $0$ and $1$ at the ends. 
 It also makes $\{0,1/2\}$ and $\{1/2,1\}$ open, which will be important for using van Kampen below.)  We now consider the space $$X=FS(8)\times I(3)/\sim$$ where $\sim$ is the equivalence relation that collapses all of $FS(8)\times\{1\}$ to a point and collapses $FS(8)\times\{0\}$ to a copy of $FS(4)$ by the equivalence relation given by $p$.  We think of $X$ as a union $\{1\}\cup FS(8)\cup FS(4)$, where $\{1\}$ is the image of $FS(8)\times\{1\}$, $FS(8)$ is the image of $FS(8)\times \{1/2\}$, and $FS(4)$ is the image of $FS(8)\times\{0\}$.

I claim $\pi_1(X)\cong\mathbb{Z}/2$.  To prove this, let $U=FS(4)\cup FS(8)\subset X$ and $V=FS(8)\cup\{1\}\subset X$.  Then $U$ and $V$ are open in $X$ and path-connected, and $U\cap V=FS(8)$ is also path-connected, so we can use them to compute $\pi_1(X)$ by van Kampen's theorem.

To identify $\pi_1(U)$, let $f:U\to U$ be the map that is the identity of $FS(4)$ and is $p$ on $FS(8)$.  Note that the $FS(8)$ and $FS(4)$ inside $U$ are ordered so that each element of $FS(8)$ is less than its image under $p$ in $FS(4)$ (this is because we used the product ordering on $FS(8)\times I(3)$ to construct $X$ and $1/2\leq 0$ in $X$). It follows that $x\leq f(x)$ for all $x\in U$, and so $f$ is homotopic to the identity map by Theorem 2.  Thus $U$ deformation-retracts to $FS(4)$ and so $\pi_1(U)\cong\mathbb{Z}$.  Moreover, the inclusion map $U\cap V\to U$ becomes $p:FS(8)\to FS(4)$ when composed with this deformation-retraction, and so the map $\pi_1(U\cap V)\to\pi_1(U)$ can be identified with the inclusion $2\mathbb{Z}\to\mathbb{Z}$.

In the same way, we can show that $\pi_1(V)$ deformation-retracts to $\{1\}$ and thus is contractible (just replace $p$ with the constant map $FS(8)\to \{1\}$ everywhere in the discussion above).  Thus by van Kampen, $$\pi_1(X)\cong\pi_1(U)*_{\pi_1(U\cap V)}\pi_1(V)\cong\mathbb{Z}*_{2\mathbb{Z}}\{1\}\cong\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}.$$

Comment: Thank you for all these insights, It will take me some time to get every thing!

Answer (score 2):

**Update:** Eric Wofsey points out in the comments that the construction I had did not work as stated. I had the right-ish idea but the correct details are all contained in Eric's answer.

---

I have some ideas for how you might construct an example on a space with less than $27$ points, but there are details I haven't worked out. The idea is to try to mimic the CW construction where you attach a disc to a circle with a map of degree $2$ on the boundary.

**Step 1:** There is a finite model of the circle with $4$ points, called the [pseudocircle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudocircle). Let $FS(4)=\{a, b, c, d\}$, with topology

$$ \left\{\{a,b,c,d\},\{a,b,c\},\{a,b,d\},\{a,b\},\{a\},\{b\},\emptyset \right\}.$$
Then there is a weak equivalence $S^1 \to FS(4)$, spelled out in the wikipedia article.

**Step 2:** Eric Wofsey points out in the comments that there is indeed an $8$-point model of the circle $FS(8)$ and a double cover $f\colon FS(8)\to FS(4)$ which is multiplication by $2$ on the fundamental group. This is the double cover corresponding to the index $2$ subgroup of $\pi_1 FS(4)$.

For the "attaching a disc" part, you need to be careful about what you mean by "cone". The model of cone I want to use will be of the form $X\times(\text{interval})/(\text{one of the ends})$, so we need to specify what we mean by an interval. I think the model of intervals I want will be the sets $\underline{n} = \{0,\dots,n\}$ where the basis for their topology is downward-facing rays (**edit: this is not the right topology, see Eric's answer**): these are path-connected, contractible spaces, representing an interval of length $n$. My cones will be

$$C_nX = (X\times \underline{n})/(X\times \{n\}).$$

This space contains $n$ parallel copies of $X$ along with a "cone point" that the space retracts onto.

**Step 3:** Let $Y=C_2(FS(8))$, and form the quotient space

$$ Z = Y \cup_f FS(4). $$

Then $Z$ has 13 points. Now we should be able to use van-Kampen to show the fundamental group is $\mathbb{Z}/2$. For one open set I think we want the subspace $U_1 = (X\times \{1, 2\})/(X\times \{2 \})\subset Y$ which is contractible, and the other set $U_2$ is the quotient of $X\times \{0, 1\}$ by $f$, which retracts onto the $4$-point circle. Their intersection is the $8$-point circle (**edit: again, I used the wrong topology so this will not be open, see Eric's answer**), whose inclusion into $U_2$ induces multiplication by $2$ on the fundamental group.

Comment: This won't work: the gluing $Y\cup_f FS(4)$ will completely destroy the structure that $FS(8)$ had and leave you with just a cone on $FS(4)$.  The problem is that a finiite cone consists of _just_ the base and the cone point, without an entire "open cylinder" in between that would survive after identifying the base with $FS(4)$.

Comment: Could we alter the definition of a cone by somehow including a second copy of $X$ to act as a kind of "midway point"?

Comment: Yeah, you can.  The idea is to take a 3-point space representing an "interval" and take a product to construct a "cylinder", and then collapse one end of the cylinder (if you do this with a 2-point "interval" instead, you get the two different "cones" of the thesis you linked).  This can be used to construct a 13-point space which you can show works by van Kampen.  I'll elaborate in an answer in a while.

Comment: I think I also found a way to take $X\times(\text{Sierpinski space})$ and then add a cone point, which might end up being homeomorphic to what you have in mind.

Comment: You can do that but that won't work for then gluing in $FS(4)$ on the other end of the cone.  (There is an overarching theory here which I am very familiar with which makes the right answers to these questions clear and which is a bit complicated to explain.  I'll tell some of the story in my answer.)

Comment: I changed my definition of cone to something that seems more compatible with homotopy theory. I feel like I'm still getting it wrong, but your answer should sort things out in any case.

Comment: Your construction of $Y$ is contractible, since you can deformation-retract the entire space to the cone point.  Note that your $U_1$ is not open since $\{1,2\}$ is not open in your $\underline{2}$.

Comment: Thank you for your corrections and your answer. I'm glad I was at least somewhat on the right path, and I learned quite a bit about finite topologies in the last day or so.

Comment: Thank you @William , I learned a lot!